# Exception AttributeError: "'KafkaProducer' object has no attribute '_closed'"

Tags: kafka-python

While producing kafka messages using kafka-python:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='192.168.1.6:9092')
producer.send('test', b'Welcome Nagarajan').get(timeout=60)
```

This Exception is being generated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 245, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = client.check_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 607, in check_version
    connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 575, in connect
    raise Errors.NodeNotReadyError(node_id)
kafka.common.NodeNotReadyError: None
```